# How to find a substring in a Sqlite table?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am creating a database with python Sqlite3 and I am trying to collect some specific rows in this table. This is the format for each row:

```py
{
"DATA":"my_variable Test should12 be substring of this",
}
```

Here is that part of my code which I need to solve:

```py
rows = curs.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATA LIKE :my_variable", {"my_variable": my_variable}).fetchall()

print(rows)
```

And my_variable could take any string. my_variable is a python string and is my_variable= 'should12'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sqlite [LIKE operator](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) is used for pattern matching. And you should use [parametrized queries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) to prevent (the very real) threat of SQL injection.

The statement will be something like this (using *named* style)

`curs.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(DATA) LIKE :my_variable",{"my_variable" : "%should12 be%" })`

Comment: Sorry but it does not find a substring, for example can't find `should12` in `"my_variable Test should12 be substring of this"`, it just returns empty

Comment: Is this `{"DATA":"my_variable Test should12 be substring of this",
}` literal (in other words, column is JSON format)? It's possible I mangled the syntax; what is the exact statement you are using?

Comment: Minor thing: `LIKE` is case-insensitive by default; don't really need that `lower()`.

Comment: @ElisaFo Are you using `should12` or `%should12%`? Should be the latter.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus Imodified my question, it's json most probably

Comment: @Shawn Please have a look, I modified my question.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks problem solved by changing a bit the answer like {"my_variable": '%{}%'.format(my_variable)}

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus Thanks problem solved by changing a bit the answer like {"my_variable": '%{}%'.format(my_variable)}